A/FD Landing Weight Codes
The airport for the example shows only an S-17 for the runway bearing strength code in the Chart Supplement (A/FD). I understand this to mean single wheel per leg up to 17000lbs total landing weight.
Does this mean that “tandem or dual wheel” configured aircraft or larger can’t land there since it isn’t listed?
I remember vaguely a single wheel equivalent somewhere but didn’t know if someone had a reference to point me in the right direction or on any regulations regarding the matter.

The document does not indicate aircraft are not allowed, this is the other way around. It indicates what are the types known as allowed, as reported by the airfield owner. Other types may be allowed but this is unknown. From the Chart Supplement:

When different wheel configurations have been evaluated, they are all listed, e.g:

RWY 02–20: H6000X150 (ASPH–GRVD) S–66, D–150, 2D–336


If aircraft with some wheel type can land, but the maximum weight is unknown from FAA, this is indicated by leaving the figures blank, e:g: S–66, D-.

AUW All up weight is used as an indicator strictly based on weight:

Maximum weight bearing capacity for any aircraft irrespective of landing gear configuration.


RWY 173–353: H3515X150 (ASPH–PFC) AUW PCN 59 F/A/W/T


SWL Single Wheel Loading

Information submitted in terms of Equivalent Single Wheel Loading (ESWL) and Single Isolated Wheel Loading)

(no example found)

In any case

When desiring to operate into any airport at weights in excess of those published in the publication, users should contact the airport management for permission.



